# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 while working with ArrayList

Tags: java, list, exception, arraylist

I m trying to store all these elements and i m getting error  like `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0` and I'm not sure what my mistakes are.

```
public List<AddUserInformation> insertData(AddUserDetail user) {
    List<AddUserInformation> inserted = null;
    try{
        List<AddUserInformation> addUserInformation = new ArrayList<AddUserInformation>() ;
        ArrayList accName = new ArrayList();

        for (int i = 0; i < user.getListofaccounts().toArray().length ; i++) {
            accName.add(user.getListofaccounts().get(i).getAccountName());                  
        }

        List<AddUserInformation> addUserInformation1 = new ArrayList<AddUserInformation>();
        for (int i = 0; i< accName.toArray().length; i++) {   
            addUserInformation1.get(i).setUserID(user.getUserId());
            addUserInformation1.get(i).setUsername(user.getUsername());
            addUserInformation1.get(i).setPassword(user.getPassword());
            addUserInformation1.get(i).setEmailid(user.getEmailid()); 
            List<AddUserAccountDetails> adduseraccountdetails = new ArrayList<>();
            addUserInformation1.get(i).setAccountName(user.getListofaccounts().get(i).getAccountName());
            addUserInformation1.get(i).setPermission_id(user.getListofaccounts().get(i).getPermission_id());
        }
        inserted = adduserInformationDao.saveAddUserInfo(addUserInformation1);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Exception in adding of account to a user " + user.getUsername(), e);
    }
    return inserted;
}
```

The thing is accName contains number of accounts lets say 'n' as list and  in the second "for" loop finally to replaces new values and showing last list values.

Answer (score 1):

The statement:

`List<AddUserInformation> addUserInformation1 = new ArrayList<AddUserInformation>();`

creates a **new empty `ArrayList`**, so when you write `addUserInformation1.get(i)` in the for loop, **you are trying to access the element at index `0` but the list is still empty** (no element at `0`), so you get the exception.

You must add something to your list (e.g., invoking `add(...)` method) before trying to `get(...)` elements.

Comment: any alternate solution for this.

Comment: Please try to add something like the following statement at the beginning of your second `for` block:
`addUserInformation1.add(new AddUserInformation());`

Answer (score 0):

**As Robert mentioned, you are trying to access an element that is not exist.**

Note:  The `List<AddUserAccountDetails> adduseraccountdetails = new ArrayList<>();` is never in use ..

You can create an object of class `AddUserInformation` then add it to your list like this:

```
    public List<AddUserInformation>  insertData(AddUserDetail user) {
       List<AddUserInformation>  inserted = null;
        try{
            List<AddUserInformation> addUserInformation = new ArrayList<AddUserInformation>() ;
            ArrayList accName = new ArrayList();

            for( int i = 0; i < user.getListofaccounts().toArray().length ; i++ ) {
               accName.add(user.getListofaccounts().get(i).getAccountName());   
            }
            List<AddUserInformation> addUserInformation1 = new ArrayList<AddUserInformation>();
            for(int i = 0; i< accName.toArray().length; i++) {   
                AddUserInformation obj = new AddUserInformation ();
                obj.setUserID(user.getUserId());
                obj.setUsername(user.getUsername());
                obj.setPassword(user.getPassword());
                obj.setEmailid(user.getEmailid()); 
                obj.setAccountName(user.getListofaccounts().get(i).getAccountName());
                obj.setPermission_id(user.getListofaccounts().get(i).getPermission_id());
                addUserInformation1.add(obj);
                }
            inserted = adduserInformationDao.saveAddUserInfo(addUserInformation1);
          }catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Exception in adding of account to a user " + user.getUsername(), e);
        }
        return inserted;
    }
```